# How can i faster my code (matrix, sapply, lapply)

Tags: r, time, simulation, lapply, sapply

i use this code. But it is Very time consuming. how can i faster this. Can any help?

```
veri=replicate(1000, sim.VSS(ncases=3000, nvariables=20, nfactors=1, meanloading=0.5,dichot=1,cut=0))
#save date set
for (i in 1:1000){
  write.csv(veri[,,i], paste("v_30002005d_", i, ".csv", sep=""))
}

#read csvs
files<- lapply(1:1000, function(x) { read.csv(paste0("v_30002005d_", x, ".csv"))}[,2:21])

formula<-  function(a){
  sapply(1:nrow(a), function(x) sapply(1:ncol(a), 
                                       function (y) {{ifelse((as.matrix(rowMeans(a)))[x,]+as.matrix(colMeans(a))[y]>=1 , a[x,y]+as.matrix(item.exam(a)$Item.Rel.woi)[y,],a[x,y])}})
  )}

new_mat=sapply(1:1000, function(z){t(formula(files[[z]]))})
```

Comment: What part is slow? Have you tried profiling the code to find the bottle necks? Reading/writing could be improved by running the code in parallel.

Comment: Before writing for a third point, I wanted to ask this: Do you need to have  matrix objects for rowMeans and colMeans? They are created as one dimensional vector objects unless you convert them into matrices and subsetting a matrix is much less efficient than subsetting a vector.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, how likely is reading/writing in parallel to hit I/O bottlenecks?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik new_mat is so slow

Comment: actually i want to use matrix because in the data set (3000(row)x20(col)) i calculate rowmeans and colmeans. Then if sum of this greater than 1, i add item reliability this value (for example 1+item reliability). If i use vector i cant do this process.

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

- The rowMeans(a) part is recalculated in each iteration inside sapply(1:ncol(a)) and also sapply(1:nrow(a)). The same is true for the colMeans(a) part. For a large object that will take too long and has a O(m * n^2) time for the dimensions n and m (so the execution time increases with the cube of the dimension for a square object). Instead of stuffing everthing inside the closure, you can calculate the row and column means at the beginning of "formula" function and assign those values to objects. A neater way is to define that innermost function separately and make function call to it (which may have some penalty due to call, but make the code more elegant and trackable)
- Instead of two sapply's for rows and columns you can use outer which is the two dimensional version of ply's. However for this to work the function inside must be vectorized. You can define a vectorized version of a function x by y <- Vectorize(x)

Comment: I'm not sure how much good the second point will do. But the first is definitely worthwhile.

Comment: I corrected my point, because the case is even worse: There are two nested plys, so the big O is cubic instead of square.